# Zimbra: block outgoing e-mail flood?

Tags: email, block, zimbra

I manage a Zimbra server with 500+ users.
One of my users got her password stolen and the spammer used her account to spam through my server.
The result was a flood of outgoing mail.

Is there a way to block a user account (not the IP) if the number of mail per minutes is more than a certain threshold?

I could not block the IP (using fail2ban for example) because I am using zimbraproxy, so in the zimbra logs I have the zimbraproxy IP as source, not the real source IP.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only setup a user "daylimit" after that it won't send any email at all (legit ones too).
[Here there is a guide](http://forums.zextras.com/zimbra-howto/579-limit-mail-account-can-send.html)